# JPA dataIntegrityViolationException occurs for multiple parents

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on simple spring security demo and want to put user and role info into db. Here is the simple structure of my entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<UserRoleMapping> userRoleMapping;
}
```

//

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role_mapping")
public class UserRoleMapping {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_role_mapping_id")
private Long userRoleMappingId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Users users;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private UserRole userRole;
}
```

//

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_role")
public class UserRole {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "role_id")
private Long roleId;

@Column(name = "role")
private String role;

@Column(name = "role_desc")
private String roleDesc;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRole", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
private List<UserRoleMapping> userRoleMapping;
}
```

In my use case, I have to make sure when the user is created then I have to insert subsequence userRoleMapping. And If the userRole is removed then the userRoleMapping must be deleted as well.

So I put CascadeType.ALL and orphanRemoval=true in users entity, and orphanRemoval=true in userRole entity.

However, when I run userRoleRepository.delete(userRole). I have dataIntegrityViolationException.

I did some researches on it and understand it is a kind of jpa constrains to make sure we delete the parents (users) as well.

May I ask if there are any workaround for my use case?

Thanks

Comment: Don't you need `CascadeType.ALL` on `UserRole::userRoleMapping` as well?

Comment: However, I can't save the userRoleList when call the userRepository.save if I don't have the cascadeType.ALL. Or you suggest me to save the child manually?

Comment: Don't know, worked all fine for me as was.

Comment: OK then. Let me try it out again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my use cases. Instead of using OneToMany in both entity, I should use ManyToMany relationship. And it is quite make sense as I don't care (for now) the mapping in java logic. Here is my code

```
public class Users {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
@JoinTable
private Set<UserRole> userRole;
}
```

//

```
public class UserRole {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "role_id")
private Long roleId;

@Column(name = "role")
private String role;

@Column(name = "role_desc")
private String roleDesc;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRole", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Users> users;
}
```